# How to fetch all aws resources in all regions in lambda function, with boto3 lib

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-config

I am tring to log all my aws resources in all regions, (with multiple accounts) using boto3 lib.

I found that aws config is helpful.

I have already created aggregator

```
  ConfigurationAggregator:
    Type: 'AWS::Config::ConfigurationAggregator'
    Properties:
      AccountAggregationSources:
        - AccountIds: !Ref AccountIds
          AllAwsRegions: !Ref AllAwsRegions
      ConfigurationAggregatorName: MyAggregator
```

And i went through boto3 lib docs for aws config
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/config.html#ConfigService.Client.batch_get_aggregate_resource_config

But it requires various REQUIRED parameters like resourceid , region account id, resource type.

Which is the simplest boto3 API where i don't have to pass anything except Aggregator name, and in return i get list of all and everykind kind of aws resources, in all the regions.

I am not worried about whether resource is complianced or not, i just want to log each and every resource in one go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to create an multi acc / multi region [aggregator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/setup-aggregator-console.html)
And use that aggregator name in below [aggregation function](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/config.html#ConfigService.Client.list_aggregate_discovered_resources)

```
            nextToken = ""
            res = []
            while (nextToken != None):
                data = client.list_aggregate_discovered_resources(ConfigurationAggregatorName=AWS_AGG_NAME, ResourceType=tp, Limit=AGG_LIMIT, NextToken=nextToken)
                do_your_logic_with_resource(rc)
                res = res + data['ResourceIdentifiers']
                nextToken = data['NextToken'] if 'NextToken' in data else None
            return res
```

Comment: were you able to create the aggregator via boto as well? or did you create the aggregator in the console (per the link)?

Answer (score 0):

I think [select_aggregate_resource_config](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/config.html#ConfigService.Client.select_aggregate_resource_config) is what you need. Example of query can be: `SELECT resourceId, resourceName, resourceType`. You can play with advanced queries in AWS Web Console before you try it in code.